# no module named app

Tags: html, python, flask, crud

El trabajo era hacer un crud con mysql, python y flask.
El detalle que tengo es que al momento de que yo lo depuro me sale la dirección y abajo ese mensaje de "no module named app" (no hay un modulo llamado app), tengo el py de la siguiente manera "app.py" ahí es donde tengo todo la configuración como el arranque y aparte mis carpetas "tamplates", el "js", "static y "*pycache*" todo en una carpeta:

[image: carpeta de trabajo "Taller Desarrollo"]

---

Este sería mi código de "app.py":

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash

from werkzeug.utils import redirect

from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'many random bytes'

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'cablenext'


mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/')
def principal():
    return render_template('cable_next.html')

@app.route('/ofertas.html')
def principal2():
    return render_template('ofertas.html')

@app.route('/contactanos.html')
def principal3():
    return render_template('contactanos.html')

@app.route('/cable_next.html')
def principal4p():
    return render_template('cable_next.html')

@app.route('/registrarse.html')
def Index():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM clientes")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()

    return render_template('registrarse.html', usuario=data)


@app.route('/insert', methods = ['POST'])
def insert():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        flash("Dato insertado correctamente")
        contraseña = request.form['contraseña']
        telefono = request.form['telefono']
        correo = request.form['correo']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO clientes (contraseña, telefono, correo) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (contraseña, telefono, correo))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('Index'))

@app.route('/delete/<string:id>', methods = ['GET'])
def delete(id):
    flash("El dato se borro correctamente")
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM clientes WHERE id=%s", (id))
    mysql.connection.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('Index'))



(app, mysql)

@app.route('/update', methods= ['POST','GET'])
def update():
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        flash("El dato se actualizó correctamente")
        id_data = request.form['id']
        contraseña = request.form['contraseña']
        telefono = request.form['telefono']
        correo = request.form['correo']

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("""UPDATE clientes SET contraseña=%s, telefono=%s, correo=%s WHERE id=%s""", (contraseña, telefono, correo, id_data))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('Index'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

Al momento de depurar me sale con este resultado en mi navergador:

[image: consola visual estudio code]

[image: resultado en el navegador con depuración]

[image: resulato en el navegador con ejecutar el archivo]

Comment: no tengo ni idea flask, pero   no encentrará tu app.py. Cambia el nombre al fichero app para no conducir...porque a todo lo llamas app

Comment: Ejecuta py app.py directamente en la carpeta donde esta app.py por linea de comandos

Comment: renombre el fichero a webapp.py y ejecute py webbap.py...y el servidor arranco

Comment: luego cree y la carpeta templates y hay meti el fichero clave_next

Comment: lame a http://127.0.0.1:5000/ desde el explorador y me renderizo la página perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

1. Seguí los paso de la instalación de flask
2. Renombre el fichero a webapp.py y ejecute py webbap.py...y el
   servidor arranco
3. Luego cree la carpeta templates y hay metí el fichero clave_next.html
4. Llame a 127.0.0.1:5000 desde el explorador y me renderizo la página
   perfectamente